# Fast and easy OS X app, to copy and paste and store and retrieve, code and text back fast?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, copy-paste

Sometimes when coding I use TextEdit to copy and paste some snippets in it, buts it's not efficient.

So I look for some personal recommendations for a fast easy OS X app to copy and paste and store and retrieve code / text back fast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select snippets of text and drag them to the Desktop, thus creating a Text Clipping file that you can drag back to another app.

Comment: ah... just select and drag and drop to the desktop, never tried that didn't even knew that was possible! Another great example how keen OSX and how terrible Windows Sucks compared to it! thx Im going to use this

Comment: @Rubytastic, BTW, you don't *have* to use the Desktop: you may want to use another folder to keep those snippets.